# Is there a way to create an alias for a column name every time it is called in Laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a model course who has a mentor_id column. Is there a way to call `Course::find($id);` and return with the column alias `mentor` instead of `mentor_id`? Is there a way to do it without having to select which columns are returned? It is a rather large table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You can create a Mutator to "fake" a field and instead return a real field.

example:

```
public function getMentorAttribute()
{
     return $this->mentor_id;
}
```

Now, you can call:

```
Course::find($id)->mentor;
```

Check the [Mutators Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators)

Comment: Awesome! is there a way to ignore the original column? Also, is there a way to make it so the "fake" field shows up when you call ```Course::find($id)```?

Comment: I dont think so, but why you need to do that?

Comment: I am writing an ember.js app and it expects mentor as a column name and not mentor_id

Comment: yea it definitely will work. i was just trying to clean up a bit and not have duplicate information in my JSON.